# Get JSON Object from JSON Response in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I want to fetch LoginOperationResponseBody key from the following JSON response in Swift.

```
[
    {
        "LoginOperationResponseHeader": {
            "ReponseCode": 1,
            "ReponseType": "Success",
            "ReponseDesc": "Login com successo"
        },
        "LoginOperationResponseBody": {
            "UserName": "dev hélio africano monteiro querido varela",
            "Email": "helio.varela@uniteltmais.cv",
            "Perfil": "perfil_002",
            "TipoCliente": "Particular",
            "NIF": 0,
            "PhotoId": 47212,
            "NomeCompleto": "dev hélio africano monteiro querido varela",
            "Number": 9100141,
            "TipoClienteId": 1,
            "TelefoneFixo": 0,
            "UserID": 122,
            "Morada": 0,
            "ClientId": 22106,
            "SessionId": "BBA72CDD-6BAA-4C22-AE95-8A674764CE7D",
            "ClientNumber": 1000481
        }
    }
]
```

If anyone could help me would be appreciated. I can fetch it if there is a key on first array Object but how can I get it without key.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's I know I want to get it without model.
Need direct JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let loginOperationResponseBody = response[0]["LoginOperationResponseBody"]
```

I found it by myself.